# How to restore network preferences in OS X?

Tags: macos, network, backup, vpn

I took my SSD, plugged it into another Mac, and booted the system (OS X 10.10.4) there. When I opened the Network Preferences, I was surprised to find, that all VPN services had disappeared. I am guessing they are somehow bound to the Mac address of the network device. When I took the disk back to the original Mac the VPN connections did not come back...

Is there a way to restore the VPN settings from my Time Machine Backup? What files do I need to restore?

Comment: I'd go for a total 'restore' to last [original machine] TM backup - I just migrated to a new machine & am having similar issues… everything 'knows' it's not the same machine, even though all else is equal.

Comment: I'm having the same question. I've tampered with my network settings while  thinking I was working on a copy of them, but obviously I did not complete the copy, so I destroyed my original settings. Now I wonder how to get them back from TM.